# After unholding CallKit, the audio does not restore

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, mobile-development, callkit

In my application, I use CallKit and have supportsHolding = true set.

During my phone call, another call comes in (e.g., GSM). I accept the incoming call and put the current call on hold.

If I end the active call myself, everything is fine, and CallKit calls the method provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession).

However, if the other party ends the call, the second call remains on hold. In the application, the user clicks on unhold, and I notify CallKit that the hold has ended.

But in this case, the didActivate method is not called at all. If I try to activate the audio myself after unhold, I receive the `error: Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "Session activation failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session activation failed}`

```
AVAudioSessionErrorInsufficientPriority == NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code: 561017449
```

What needs to be done for CallKit to activate my audio?

[Code example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/making-and-receiving-voip-calls-with-callkit)